# Removing files from repository while merging makes them disappear

Tags: git, git-merge

Here is a test repo demonstrating the problem: https://bitbucket.org/vektor330/bugtest

The sequence of events is this:

1. Add some initial commit.
2. Person A adds `Conflict` and `source` to `develop`.
3. Person B adds `Conflict` to `master`.
4. Person B merges `develop` into `master`, resolving conflict on `Conflict` using "mine" strategy, and removing `source` from the repository. This is now an empty commit, but can be commited and pushed back to remote.

The result is: `source` has disappeared completely from the repository. It appeared in 7dfa23e, there is a log of it appearing in the repo, and it quietly disappeared in 5080a24, without a single trace.

I would expect the commit 5080a24 to show "`source` removed", what is wrong with Git or my expectation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why this wouldn't show as the "content of the merge commit".

You can visualize the content of the merge commit by selecting the merge commit and each of the two parents in turn.

When you select (in SourceTree) the one from the develop branch (in addition of the merge commit), you clearly see that `files_to_lose/source` have been removed:

[image: diff]

> Why does the commit itself not show the missing file?

Because in the case of a merge commit, there are two parents to compare against. SourceTree doesn't offer the diff against those two parents.

GitHub for Mac or Windows does, when you select *only* the merge commit:

[image: GitHub for Windows]

In short, this isn't about Git, just about the Git GUI that you are using.

Comment: I know I can (see my comment to the other question), but it's something I wouldn't normally feel to be necessary to do. Why does the commit itself not show the missing file?

Comment: @vektor I have amended my answer to address your question.

Comment: Thanks for the GitHub example, it did not occur to me that BitBucket and SourceTree probably show the same thing on the account of having the same engine and I attributed this to Git. Once it's possible to award the bounty, it's yours!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing "What is stored in Git" and "What BitBucket shows you". There's two separate parents and you can compare against each of those by clicking on the links on the right in BitBucket's interface.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Which links? Usually, I would do this in SourceTree, and yes - the missing file would be clearly marked when comparing 5080a24 and 7dfa23e. I am asking why this wouldn't show as the "content of the merge commit".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your question is about bitbucket, or about git.  However, in git, you need to run `git show` with the `-m` flag to show a merge commit.  Adding that flag reveals the deleted file:

```
$ git show --summary -m 5080a24
commit 5080a24f6585af2b38161ba55ec4835c7171634d (from 7dfa23e1bfc0a460bfe8071e3623ce9b5959a785)
Merge: a8a08dc 7dfa23e
Author: Matej VitaÌsek <vektor330@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 8 09:58:05 2015 +0200

    Hahaaa, a hidden files commit!

 delete mode 100644 files_to_lose/source
$
```